# How to ship gdiplus.dll but not have Windows use it?

Tags: dll, assemblies, gdi+, dependencies, fusion

i have an application that has a dependancy on gdiplus. i need the application to also run on Windows 2000.

i want to include GDIPlus in the application directory, so that Windows 2000 computers will function, but if the machine is Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, etc, i want it to use the version of GDIPlus that ships, and is updated, with Windows.

Not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997620.aspx Try adding the following to your manifest :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"
         name="Microsoft.Windows.mysampleapp" type="win32" />
    <description>Your app description here</description>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus"
                version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"
                publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. i verified that fusion wasn't using my local version with Process Explorer. The path of gdiplus was "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6002.18005_none_9e50b396ca17ae07\gdiplus.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Won't it be easier to do it from the installer ? IF you are installing on Windows 2000 copy Gdiplus to application directory otherwise skip it.

Comment: There's no installer. Its sitting in a shared folder on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

From the [GDI+ page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798.aspx):

> Run-time Requirements
>
> Gdiplus.dll is included with Windows
>   XP. For information about which
>   operating systems are required to use
>   a particular class or method, see the
>   More Information section of the
>   documentation for the class or method.
>   GDI+ is available as a redistributable
>   for Windows NT 4.0 SP6, Windows 2000,
>   Windows 98, and Windows Me. To
>   download the latest redistributable,
>   see
>   http://www.microsoft.com/msdownload/platformsdk/sdkupdate/psdkredist.htm.

First hit on Google for "win2000 gdiplus".

Comment: Yeaaahhhhh.....  The the folder that will contain the executable will contain gdiplus.dll for operating systems that do not ship with it. How do i make operating systems that do ship with it not use my depoyed version...

Comment: There is no installer. i need to include gdi+ in the app directory for those OS's that don't ship with GDI+, but not use it on OS's that do have GDI+.